# MongoDB Upload Err - Error: key $clusterTime must not start with '$'

Tags: mongodb

I am getting an unusual error message when trying to insert data into my mongodb database. I am attempting to perform a simple insertOne operation, not even referencing any key called $clusterTime

```
db.collection("listings").insertOne( objToInsert , function(err, res) {
    if (err) { console.log(err); console.log("err"); return; }
    console.log('success');
});
```

Comment: What does your `objToInsert` object look like?

Comment: @dnickless {'test':'test'}, i was able to get it resolved thanks

Comment: Glad to hear that. Good stuff. You might want to mark your own answers as the accepted solution just to sort of close off this thread and keep it as a reference for others...

Comment: Yes, need to wait until tomorrow until i can mark my own answer as a solution

Answer (score 1):

Solution provided by Mongodb at : https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-1627?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel

Basically, upgrade from v3.1.2 to v3.1.3